# How many equilibrium points exist?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Here comes the definition of a simple potential function

```
Clear["Global`*"];
r1 = Sqrt[(x + μ)^2 + y^2];
r2 = Sqrt[(x - 1 + μ)^2 + y^2];
Ω = (1 - μ)/r1 + μ/r2 - p/(2*c^4)*((1 - μ)^3/r1^3 + μ^3/r2^3) + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);

μ = 1/2;
p = 0.01;
c = 1;

Ωx = D[Ω, x];
Ωy = D[Ω, y];

f[x_, y_] := Ωx
g[x_, y_] := Ωy
```

Now I want to determine how many equilibrium points exist when $p = 0.01$ and also when $p = 0.9$. Let's start with $p = 0.01$.

```
Options[FindRoots2D] = {WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 30};

FindRoots2D[funcs_, {x_, a_, b_}, {y_, c_, d_}, opts___] := 
Module[{fZero, seeds, signs, fy}, 
 fy = Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate[funcs[[2]]]];
 fZero = 
 Cases[Normal[
 ContourPlot[
  funcs[[1]] == 0, {x, a - (b - a)/97, b + (b - a)/103}, {y, 
   c - (d - c)/98, d + (d - c)/102}, 
  Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ContourPlot]]]]], 
 Line[z_] :> z, Infinity];
 seeds = Flatten[((signs = Sign[Apply[fy, #1, {1}]];
    #1[[
     1 + Flatten[
       Position[Rest[signs*RotateRight[signs]], -1]]]]) &) /@ 
 fZero, 1];
 If[seeds == {}, {}, 
 Select[Union[({x, y} /. 
     FindRoot[{funcs[[1]], 
       funcs[[2]]}, {x, #1[[1]]}, {y, #1[[2]]}, 
      Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[FindRoot]]]] &) /@ 
  seeds, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^(-8) &)], 
 a <= #1[[1]] <= b && c <= #1[[2]] <= d &]]]

pts = FindRoots2D[{Ωx, Ωy}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 500]
nps = Length[pts];
Print["N = ", nps]
```

The code reports 27 equilibrium points, while I strongly believe that this result is false.

Let's see what the contours have to say

```
cont0 = ContourPlot[{Ωx == 0, Ωy == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
ContourShading -> False, ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Darker[Green]}, {Thick, Blue}}, 
PlotPoints -> 150, PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", 
Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Red, Point@pts}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

I believe that the correct answer is 13 equilibrium points.

Similarly for $p = 0.9$ the code reports 3 equilibrium points.

[image]

However also in this case I believe that there is only one equilibrium point at (0,0), while the other two reported points are false.

So, my question: What is the correct number of equilibrium points for $p = 0.01$ and for $p = 0.9$? Needless to say that any proposition of another alternative way of correctly computing the number of equilibrium points is more than welcome!

I am using v9.0 of Mathematica.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to use `f[x_, y_] = Ωx` instead of `f[x_, y_] := Ωx`?  Didn't read the rest of the post, but this shouldn't work with `:=`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Strangely the code works fine wither with `:=` or simply with `=`

Comment: Yes, but it seems that you don't actually use `f` and `g` ... Looking at higher resolution contour plots, it appears that there are an infinite number of equilibrium points which all lay on a circle.  (This may not be exactly true, but it will throw off th numerics)

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, I still believe that this (infinite points) is actually a numerical artefact. Take $p = 0.2$ and inspect the contours. You will see that there are four points in this area. Now as you tend to $p = 0$ the four points come close and finally for $p = 0$ they disappear.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it must be a numerical artefact. It is also what makes the problem numerically difficult.

Comment: @Szabolcs OK, if the case $p = 0.01$ it's not easy what about the case $p = 0.9$? This looks much easier.

Comment: It seems to be possible to brute force the difficult case using `Length@FindRoots2D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5]` (perhaps also using `WorkingPrecision -> 40` and setting `p=1/100` exactly). This returns 13.  It does not prove that this answer is correct, but there are indications that it is, such as your observations about the contour plot when p is increased, looking at the numerical value of the result as WorkingPrecision is increased further, and that the FindRoot errors are gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed a lot of `FindRoot::cvmit` errors when you run `FindRoots2D`.  I wrapped a `Check` around the `FindRoot` in `FindRoots2D` that effectively excludes these nonconvergent points (by returning points that are out of bounds by 999 and therefore discarded). This gives the answers you suspect.

```
FindRoots2D[funcs_, {x_, a_, b_}, {y_, c_, d_}, opts___] := 
Module[{fZero, seeds, signs, fy}, 
fy = Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate[funcs[[2]]]];
fZero = 
  Cases[Normal[ContourPlot[
    funcs[[1]] == 0, {x, a - (b - a)/97, b + (b - a)/103}, {y, c - (d - c)/98, d + (d - c)/102}, 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ContourPlot]]]]], 
    Line[z_] :> z, Infinity];

seeds = Flatten[((signs = Sign[Apply[fy, #1, {1}]];
 #1[[1 + Flatten[Position[Rest[signs*RotateRight[signs]], -1]]]]) &) /@ fZero, 1];
If[seeds == {}, {}, 
Select[Union[({x, y} /. 
  Check[
    FindRoot[{funcs[[1]], funcs[[2]]}, {x, #1[[1]]}, {y, #1[[2]]}, 
      Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[FindRoot]]]],
  {x -> b + 999, y -> d + 999}] &) /@ seeds, 
  SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^(-8) &)], 
  a <= #1[[1]] <= b && c <= #1[[2]] <= d &]]]

pts = FindRoots2D[{Ωx, Ωy}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 500];
nps = Length[pts];
Print["N = ", nps]

(* 13 *)
```

Comment: That is simply marvelous! Many thanks :)

Comment: This is obviously a quick hack.  Maybe a better approach would be to test all the putative roots whether they actually satisfy the equations?

Comment: This looks very interesting. The `FindRoots2D` module creates the list `pts` of possible roots. Then how can we easily filter them and see which of them are actually satisfy the system of equations?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
cont1 = ContourPlot[(Ωx /. {μ -> 1/2, c -> 1, p -> 1/100}) == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Darker[Red]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], PlotPoints -> 100, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Tiny], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Small], AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium];
cont2 = ContourPlot[(Ωy /. {μ -> 1/2, c -> 1, p -> 1/100}) == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Darker[Blue]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], PlotPoints -> 100, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Tiny], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Small], AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium];
```

The equilibria:

```
p0 = {x, y} /. DeleteDuplicates[NSolve[({Ωx, Ωy} /. {μ -> 1/2, c -> 1, p -> 1/100}) == {0, 0}, {x, y}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 650]];
Length[p0]
(*13*)
N[Table[{Ωx, Ωy} /. {μ -> 1/2, c -> 1, p -> 1/100} /. {x -> p0[[i]][[1]], y -> p0[[i]][[2]]}, {i, 1, Length[p0]}]]
(*{{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}*)
```

ContourPlot:

```
Show[cont1, cont2, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> {{PointSize[0.012], Black, Point@p0}}]
```

[image]